# Read array of values export in blocks of formatted LaTeX?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to read a table like this:

```
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
.. .. ..
xn yn zn
```

And then have my code print a text file that looks like this:

```
\object{x1}
\ra{y1}
\dec{z1}

\object{x2}
\ra{y2}
\dec{z2}

\object{..}
\ra{..}
\dec{..}

\object{xn}
\ra{yn}
\dec{zn}
```

Thus far, I have a code that reads in these arrays just fine, but I do not know how to save them to a text file that's anything other than exactly what was read in. Is there a way I can have each of these lines printed in some customized format, like above?

I've tried

np.savetxt('data.txt',zip(x,y,z),fmt='(messing with formatting options here)')

but I've had no luck and I'm not sure if savetxt is even the right route. Thanks very much in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array `arr` and want your output in a file, you can try:

```
arr = [['x1','y1','z1'],
       ['x2','y2','z2'],
       ['x3','y3','z3']]


with open('latex.txt', 'a') as myfile:
    [myfile.write('\object{'+row[0]+'}\n\\ra{'+row[1]+'}\n\dec{'+row[2]+'}\n\n') for row in arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```py
import numpy as np

txt = np.genfromtxt('input.txt', dtype='str')

# python >= 3.6
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write("\n".join(
        [f'\\object{{{row[0]}}}\n'
         f'\\ra{{{row[1]}}}\n'
         f'\\dec{{{row[2]}}}\n'
         '\\color{red}\n' # static line
         for row in txt]
    ))

# python < 3.6
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write("\n".join(
        ['\\object{{{row[0]}}}\n'
         '\\ra{{{row[1]}}}\n'
         '\\dec{{{row[2]}}}\n'
         '\\color{{red}}\n'.format(row=row) # static line
         for row in txt]
    ))
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! If I needed more lines that didn't take an input (ones that are static every iteration) would I do it like this?: `f'\\color{{{red}}}\n'` (if I just wanted the output to say `\object{red}` )

Comment: Sorry, actually I'm getting a syntax error after the }}}\n'

Comment: For static lines you would only need two curly braces. In the dynamic case 3 braces are needed: The first `{` escapes the `{` that will actually appear in the output. The third `{` is needed to escape the python variable. I updated my answer with a additional static line.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm still getting a syntax error:  `File "test2.py", line 8 [f'\\object{{{row[0]}}}\n' ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: 2.7.15 is what I have right now

edit: also have 3.4, but getting the same error

Comment: the second solution should now also work for python2

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the reading and writing processes. A solution involving the use of the module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html), to read comma separated values from a file (in this case, not a comma but a space).
Here `data.txt` is the file with the table, `out.txt` the file with the format you want.

```
import csv

with open('data.txt') as rr:
    reader = csv.reader(rr, delimiter=' ')
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as oo:
        for line in reader:
            oo.write(f"\\object{{{line[0]}}}\n")
            oo.write(f"\\ra{{{line[1]}}}\n")
            oo.write(f"\\dec{{{line[2]}}}\n\n")
```

Notice the triple curly braces in the [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) two braces to print a brace, one to print the variable value.

If your python version is < 3.6, use instead:

```
oo.write("\\object{{{}}}\n".format(line[0]))
oo.write("\\ra{{{}}}\n".format(line[1]))
oo.write("\\dec{{{}}}\n\n".format(line[2]))
```

#### EDIT after comment

To add extra lines each block, simply write them with an extra call to `oo.write` inside the `for` loop. For example:

```
oo.write(f"\\object{{{line[0]}}}\n")
oo.write(f"\\ra{{{line[1]}}}\n")
oo.write(f"\\dec{{{line[2]}}}\n")
oo.write("\color{red}\n\n") #no need to use format here, one curly bracket is enough
```

Last line does not depend on `line`, so will be the same each iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks! How would I add a static line to this? Like if there was one I just wanted to say \color{red} in every block?